# BBedit Option "Run" or "Run in terminal"

Tags: fortran, bbedit

I'm a newbie to BBedit. I use this to write my f90 file. Anybody know why all the options "Run" in my bbedit window are greyed out?

I always saved my file as .f90

Comment: Fortran is [compiled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) and cannot be simply run from editor. Solution is to use build scripts such as make, cmake, etc. I recommend [make](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/index.htm) which is good for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, Fortran is not a Unix scripting language (such as Perl, Python, or Ruby).

Comment: I have Unix scripts, and the Run command is still greyed out. It says "Unix Shell Script" as the selected language. On what basis does BBEdit enable the Run command?